# Sphere is stretched when translated

Tags: 3d, processing

When I do this: (translate sphere to center)

```
translate(width/2, height/2);
noStroke();
fill(255, 0, 0);
lights();
sphere(60);
```

I get the result I should:

[image]

However, when I try to move the sphere away, say the bottom -

```
translate(width/2, height - 120);
```

I get an oval shape:

[image]

How can I get the sphere to stay round no matter how I move/translate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply stretched because of [perspective projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection), to give the illusion of depth.

To get it to appear as a circle you'll need to use an [Orthographic projection](https://processing.org/tutorials/p3d/).